# spring simplecachemanager not working on method call

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I developed simple application to test spring cache abstraction. This app uses SimpleCacheManager to store data in map. Call goes from MVC controller to service to dao. Service class method is annotated with @Cacheble("test") and is public method with one argument of type String and returns string. Now all we need to to cache those values by argument passed to this service class method.

Here is cache config

```
<cache:annotation-driven cache-manager="cacheManager" />
<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.support.SimpleCacheManager">
    <property name="caches">
        <set>
            <bean
              class="org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCacheFactoryBean"
              name="test"/>
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Method annotation looks like this

```
@Cacheable(value="test",key="#id")
public String getProductName(final String id) {
```

Somehow it always making db call. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

your cacheName ist wrong.
you write

```
@Cacheable(value="test",key="#id")
public String getProductName(final String id) {
```

with cacheName "test"
but in your config you don't have a cache with name "test"

Comment: do you see in debug outbput, that the cacheManager is created?

Comment: Yes, I do see it is being created, even I have injected CacheManager into one of our bean to see the data inside.

Comment: crazy, in my application i use the annotation without the key value. only @Cacheable(value="test")  have you tried this ?

Comment: Yes I tried that too by following examples online. But no luck. Some how it is not intercepting that method call to do caching. Dont know if I am missing any lib in class path or some other config.

Comment: i use java config but i have no additional config or libs `@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class SpringConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {


    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
     SimpleCacheManager cacheManager = new SimpleCacheManager();
     cacheManager.setCaches(Arrays.asList(new ConcurrentMapCache("test")));
     return cacheManager;
    }
}`

Comment: Well, I developed POC using spring boot it worked. Problem is I have to use spring 4.1.x and still could not figure out why simple xml config is not working. I will keep trying and post it here if it works.